# Global changes UINavigationBar background using appearance proxy not working

Tags: swift, uikit, ios13

I'm trying to change some properties of all UINavigationBars in my app using UINavigationBarAppearance.  I'm calling the following function in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in AppDelegate.swift:

```
func customizeAppearance() {

    let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    navBarAppearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
    navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    let tintColor = UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 238/255.0, blue: 136/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = tintColor

}
```

I expect this to change the background color and color of the title text, but when I run the app, only the text color changes (this is also true for the UITabBar).  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this `UINavigationBarAppearance` in your UINavigationControllers. If you use global appearance for UINavigationController you should use `UINavigationBar.appearance()` instead of `UINavigationBarAppearance()`.

Comment: Hmm.  UINavigationBar.appearance() doesn't seem to provide access to the titleTextAttributes property.

Comment: For some reason, XCode doesn't autocomplete UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor or UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes.  I'm not sure why this is, but if I type it out, it works as expected.  Thanks!